# Can this code be improved to avoid repetition?

Tags: php, cakephp, dry

Code below is a switch statement written in php. The line `$historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);` repeats in every case. This violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. Is there some way to improve the code to adhere to DRY?

```
 switch ($term)
            {
                case "1":
                    $term = 'XXX_1_year';                
                    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $term = 'XXX_2_year';                
                    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    $term = 'XXX_5_year';  
                    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
                    break;
                default:
                    print ("Invalid  parameter.");
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

obvious improvement:

```
switch ($term) {
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "5":
        $term = 'XXX_'.$term'_year';                
        $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
        break;
    default:
        print ("Invalid parameter.");
}
```

or

```
if ( ($term == '1') || ($term == '2') || ($term == '5') ) {
    $term = 'XXX_'.$term'_year';                
    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
} else {
    print ("Invalid parameter.");
}
```

or

```
if (in_array($term, array('1', '2', '5'))) {
    $term = 'XXX_'.$term'_year';                
    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
} else {
    print ("Invalid parameter.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the numerous answers which all work. I prefer the obvious one most. It is easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
 switch ($term)
            {    
                case "1":
                case "2":
                case "5":
                    $term = 'XXX_'.$term.'_year';
                    $historical_term = $this->MonthlyCurves->getHistorical($term, $start_date, $end_date);
                    break;
                default:
                    print ("Invalid  parameter.");
            }
```